# Matlab - Vectorizing some dimensions of array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

I try vectorizing a 'for loop' for array but it does not work to me.
My 'for loop' is

```
for k = 1:N
R(n,n,k) = R(n,n,k) - SE3(k,k);
end
```

and vectorize it

```
diagSE3 = diag(SE3);
R(n,n,1:N) = R(n,n,1:N) - diagSE3(1:N);
```

Comment: What are the desired results? Can you show us a `for` loop that does what you want?

Comment: It is likely to be a dimensional mismatch error - you may need a `squeeze` and/or a transpose on the output of `diag`. In future, state any errors or other problems you get, never just say code "does not work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
R(n,n,1:N) = R(n,n,1:N) - diagSE3(1:N)
```

you try to subtract a vector (N x 1) from a 3-dimensional array with dimensions 1 x 1 x N. This can be repaired using `squeeze`:

```
R(n,n,1:N) = squeeze(R(n,n,1:N)) - diagSE3(1:N)
```